# Combining Google Maps Geocoder and Leaflet Map Receiving Error: Invalid LatLng object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, leaflet, cloudmade

I'm using Google Maps Geocoder to grab the latitude and longitude of an address. I'm then taking that address and using Leaflet and panning the map to the latitude + longitude coordinates. However, I'm receiving an error from Firebug saying `Error: Invalid LatLng object: (-33.8674869, 151.20699020000006, undefined)`. I know my variable `geolocation` returns `-33.8674869, 151.20699020000006` but not the undefined. What's causing the problem?

```
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="result"></div>
 <div>
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
 </div>

 <div id="map"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 var map = L.map('map').setView([33.7489954, -84.3879824], 13);

  var geocoder;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();     
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var geolocation = String(results[0].geometry.location);

        var geolocation = geolocation.replace('(','');

        var geolocation = geolocation.replace(')','');      

        map.panTo([geolocation]);

      } else {
        $('#result').html('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  };

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/apikeyputhere/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this:

```
    var geolocation = String(results[0].geometry.location);

    var geolocation = geolocation.replace('(','');

    var geolocation = geolocation.replace(')','');      

    map.panTo([geolocation]);
```

with that:

```
map.panTo([results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
```

**Explanation:**
You assign a string to the first array-value, it's the same as:

```
geolocation=new Array('-33.8674869, 151.20699020000006')//contains 1 string
```

The string will not be evaluated, it will remain 1 string, but you need an array with 2 floats:

```
geolocation=new Array(-33.8674869, 151.20699020000006)//contains 2 floats
```

The  `undefined`  is the missing 2nd item of the array provided to `panTo()`

Comment: Amazing. Simple explanation and an answer that minimizes four lines of code into one. Thanks so much.

Comment: The documentation for [map.panTo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) specifies a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) for its argument.  If an array works, you are just lucky (it shouldn't work).  The geocoder result results[0].geometry.location is already a google.maps.LatLng, you can pass it directly to panTo.

Comment: @geocodezip: It's not a `google.maps.Map`-object , it's a `Leaflet.map`-object , where `panTo()` accepts an array as argument.