# How to use Viewport from Google Geocoder in Leaflet JS?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, leaflet

I have successfully set up a Leaflet JS map that uses the Google maps geocoder to pan to a geocoded address.  But I am also trying to use "map.fitBounds" to get the appropriate zoom level from the Viewport, but it does not seem to be working.  The code I am using is:

```
map.panTo([results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
   map.fitBounds([[results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lat(), results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lng()],[results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat(), results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lng()]]);
```

See example here: http://chrismccreath.hostzi.com/geocode_test.html

How can I fix it so that it zooms to the appropriate viewport returned by the google maps geocoder result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no properties like `results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest/northeast`(I  guess you were watching at the network-traffic inside the console, but what you see there will not be passed to the callback-function directly). To get the southwest/northeast use the methods `getSouthWest()` and `getNorthEast()` of `google.maps.LatLngBounds` .

`results[0].geometry.viewport` is a google.maps.LatLngBounds-object, but you can't use it directly in Leaflet.

You must "convert" it to an array or an Leaflet.LatLngBounds-object.

This should work:

```
map.fitBounds([
               [results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat(),
                results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lng()],
               [results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lat(),
                results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lng()]
              ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting the working example. It helped a lot. It didn't work immediately for me however, had to do some tweaking for it to work.

```
function codeAddress() {
   var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
   geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0].geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds([[results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat(),
                          results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lng()],
                        [results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lat(),
                         results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast().lng()]]);
            map.setZoom(18);
        } else if (results[0].geometry.bounds) {
            map.fitBounds([[results[0].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
                     results[0].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lng()],
                    [results[0].geometry.bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                     results[0].geometry.bounds.getNorthEast().lng()]]);
        } else { // give up, pick an arbitrary zoom level
            map.panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(15);
      }
    } else {
      $('#result').html('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Just thought I'd post it if anybody else wasn't able to figure out how to get it to work.

Thanks again!

Comment: 9 years later and this bit of code worked exactly as I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DrMolle pointed out that leaflet map objects are not Google Maps API v3 objects (in the other question you reference).  This works:

```
   map.panTo([results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
   map.fitBounds([[results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast()],
                  [results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest()]]);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_leaflet_map_geocode_test.html)

As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry):

- results[].geometry.location is a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), which panTo requires as an argument.
- results[].geometry.viewport is a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds), which fitBounds requires as an argument.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. The panTo in my example works without an error (I copied that from the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773542/combining-google-maps-geocoder-and-leaflet-map-receiving-error-invalid-latlng-o ), but, right enough, there is an error in the console for the fitBounds line - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined".  Unfortunately your suggestion does not seem to work either, and I get the same error in the console.

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me (it gives: Network Error (tcp_error), A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time).  It is conceivable that the particular result you are using doesn't contain a suggested viewport, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated suggestion.  It still fails to work (I get the same console error), I guess because of a difference in how the Leaflet and Google APIs use panTo and fitBounds?

Comment: DrMolle pointed out that leaflet map objects are not Google Maps API v3 objects (in the other question you reference). See the updated answer and working example.

Comment: The example still doesn't work, Leaflet doesn't accept  `google.maps.LatLng`-objects, as returned by `getSouthWest()` and `getNorthEast()`

Comment: What browser?  I tested it in IE (fixed a bunch of "hanging commas") and Firefox.

Comment: Leaflet [L.LatLng](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng) and [L.LatLngBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) look pretty much like their Google Maps API equivalents, but they also take arrays.

Comment: In IE8 and Chrome, the panning would work but not the zooming.  Thanks for the tip re commas.